# What does a "Reg" suffix in a source file name mean?

Tags: delphi

What kind of files are the files with a `Reg` suffix in their file name?

For example, along with the `dxPSTCLnk.pas` file (from [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/)) there is also a `dxPSTCLnkReg.pas` file.

(I am trying to build a package that includes the `dxPSTCLnk.pas` file since DevExpress no longer provides the package that I need, and I'm just wondering what this other file is about.)

When do you use the `Reg` suffix?

Comment: Usually when component builders have these 'pairs' of files of which one contains the string 'Reg', that last is one is the design-time package. It contains the Register() calls necessary to register the object in the IDE.

Comment: You could actually open the file and read it. If you did it would become obvious what it does. Why are you not doing that?

Comment: -1. Question does not show any research effort. The least you could do, if you want to know what a file is for, is to open it and see what it does. It's not Stack Overflow's role to read code for you. If you've read the code and still don't understand what it does, then identify that code and ask what it does. Demonstrate your research by showing the code and explaining how it doesn't fit with what the documentation says. (That also means you're expected to have read some documentation.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am a mathematician by training, not a programmer. However, in my small company roles overlap and I am doing my best to learn to program the GUI. It is really quite fun. Stackoverflow (especially with David Heffernan's help) has proved an invaluable resource. I read the file and realized that it was about registering components, but I didn't know what that was as I've never built a design-time package.

Comment: That's good. To get on top of this you should follow the design time package tutorial and learn how it works. Then you'll know what registering is all about. I think you need to do that once or twice yourself for the concepts to sink in.

Comment: `*reg.pas` is a common convention to place `RegisterComponents` call. These modules are going into design packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Reg` suffix is a non-standard but a frequently used manner to indicate that it is the file with code that solely takes care of registering classes, file formats, IDE services and other types into the IDE. These classes can be components, actions, property editors, graphics, component editors, etc.

If the suffix is added to a single unit source file, then it registers classes from that single unit. When the suffix is added to a design package source file, then it registers all classes from all units within that package.

Such a registering unit is often recognizable by having only a single routine - `Register` - in the interface section.

An example of a design package registration unit:

```
unit AwFrameworkReg;

interface

uses
  Classes, ActnList, DesignIntf, ADOReg, DBReg, AwActions, AwStdCtrls,
  AwDBCtrls, AwExtCtrls, AwSideBar, AwPlanGrid, AwComCtrls, AwPicture,
  AwForms, AwControlMarking, AwDBClient, AwButtons, AwStringGrid,
  AwImageGrid, AwFrameworkEdit, AwProvider, AwADODB, AwDxf, ToolsAPI,
  AwToolsAPI, AwUtils;

procedure Register;

implementation

var
  IdeNotifierIndex: Integer = -1;

procedure CreateIdeNotifier;
var
  Services: IOTAServices;
begin
  if IdeServicesAvailable then
  begin
    Services := GetServices;
    IdeNotifierIndex := Services.AddNotifier(TAwIdeNotifier.Create);
  end;
end;

procedure RegisterKeyboardBinding;
var
  Services: IOTAKeyboardServices;
begin
  if IdeServicesAvailable then
  begin
    Services := GetKeyboardServices;
    Services.AddKeyboardBinding(TAwKeyboardBinding.Create);
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  { AwStdCtrls }
  RegisterComponents('Awerdo', [TAwEdit, TAwCombo, TAwFormatEdit, TAwListBox,
    TAwCheckBox, TAwButton, TAwMemo, TAwGroupBox]);
  { AwExtCtrls }
  RegisterComponents('Awerdo', [TAwProgressBar, TAwProgressStatusBar]);
  { AwDBCtrls }
  RegisterComponents('Awerdo', [TAwDBEdit, TAwDBCombo, TAwDBSearchCombo,
    TAwDBLookupCombo, TAwDBNavigator]);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(String), TAwDBEdit, 'DataField',
    TDataFieldProperty);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(String), TAwDBCustomCombo, 'DataField',
    TDataFieldProperty);
  { AwComCtrls }
  RegisterComponents('Awerdo', [TAwTabSheet, TAwPageControl]);
  { Other }
  RegisterComponents('Awerdo', [TAwSideBar, TAwPlanGrid, TAwPicture,
    TAwDxfImage, TAwExtraMDIProps, TAwControlMarker, TAwClientDataSet,
    TAwPngBitBtn, TAwPngDropDownBitBtn, TAwStringGrid, TAwImageGrid,
    TAwProvider, TAwADOConnection, TAwADODataSet]);
  RegisterActions('Form', [TFormOpen], nil);
  RegisterComponentEditor(TAwStringGrid, TAwStringGridEditor);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TPath), TAwImageGrid, 'Folder',
    TPathProperty);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(String), TAwClientDataSet, 'CommandText',
    TCommandTextProperty);
  CreateIdeNotifier;
  RegisterKeyboardBinding;
end;

procedure RemoveIdeNotifier;
var
  Services: IOTAServices;
begin
  if IdeNotifierIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    Services := GetServices;
    Services.RemoveNotifier(IdeNotifierIndex);
  end;
end;

initialization

finalization
  RemoveIdeNotifier;

end.
```